# Recursive grammar for the language of strings

Tags: parsing, recursion, grammar

I was given the following task:

> Write a recursive grammar for the language of strings of one or more letters. The first letter of each string must be uppercase, and all other letters in the string must be lowercase.

After reading the chapter on grammar, and exploring some examples, this is my attempt:

```
<goodString> =<UpCh>|<UpCh> <ch> 

<UpCh> = A|B|C...|Z

<ch> = a|b|c...|z
```

or maybe

```
<goodString> =<UpCh>|<goodString> <ch>

<UpCh> = A|B|C...|Z

<ch> = a|b|c...|z
```

Is this right?  If not, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Why is this labeled as C++?  It appears to have everything to do with how to conceptualize the algorithm and nothing to do with the language details of how to implement it ...

Comment: @ZacHowland I was thinking the same, so I went and removed the tag.

Comment: Oh. This is actually something I am learning in my C++ based Data Structures class :)

Answer (score 3):

Right now your grammar isn't recursive. A recursive grammar would/will include at least one production that invokes itself (directly or indirectly) on the right side.

In this case, the obvious place to use that would be "an indefinite number of lower case letters". For that I'd define a lower case string (or whatever) as either nil, or a lower case string followed by a lower case letter. Then your `word` will be an upper case letter followed by a lower case string.

Note that for a case like this, you can define the lower case string as a character followed by a string, or as a string followed by a character. These are known as right recursive and left recursive respectively. If there's any chance you'll ever implement the grammar, you probably want to know that you want the right recursive form for a recursive descent parser, but generally prefer the left recursive form for a bottom up parser (such as many generators such as yacc, Bison, byacc, etc., produce).

Comment: @JohnPeterson: It's certainly a *lot* closer. Whether it's exactly right depends on the *exact* requirements for your string. Specifically, right now it'll accept a single capital letter as a "string". Is it defined as a capital letter followed by 0 or more lower-case, or by 1 or more lower-case?

Comment: Well it says "Write a recursive grammar for the language of strings of one or more letters." So I'm assuming followed by 0 or more lower case letter.

Comment: If you could provide the code for both cases, that'd be great as I could compare both to understand he concept better.

Comment: @JohnPeterson: Sorry for the "delay", but your comments were written at roughly midnight and 3:00 AM my time. In any case, I'd agree that based on your description that your current formulation is correct.